# GWT date- not allow to select date before start date

Tags: gwt, datepicker

I have two dates start date and end date from gwt . I want "not to allow user to select end date before start date in gwt". please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check start date while selecting date of end date box, something like

```
final DateBox startDateBox=new DateBox();
final DateBox endDateBox=new DateBox();
startDateBox.getDatePicker().addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
        if(endDateBox.getValue()==null)
        {
            endDateBox.setValue(null);
            Window.alert("Please select start date  before selecting end date");
        }

    }
});
```

I did not check here this code, it should work.

Comment: Users can also type in the date. Probably better to check on change in the DateBox, not just DatePicker.

Comment: And I think she meant selecting the end date that is prior in time to the start date, not the order of entering them.